# GPLv3 in a client - server program

Tags: gpl-3, website

If I develop a program which has a client which uses a framework which is licensed under GPLv3 and this client would interact with a (paid) back-end service would this be compliant with the GPLv3 license?

1. I would release the source code of the client but not the back-end service
2. Users could modify the client all they like and use the back end service (if they paid)

Comment: Why did this receive two down votes without comment? Is there something wrong with the question? Aside from a couple formatting issues (which, common everyone, a quick simple edit can fix that, and you're all capable of using it), it looks like a good on-topic question.

Comment: zizouz I'm always willing to improve my English, could you reply with what could be better? (or edit my question) so I could learn please :). on topic: I know the client needs to be open source, I just don't know if the backend needs to be open source because the client needs this back end to do anything usefull

Comment: I don't believe anything is (or was) wrong with your question, content wise or english wise. I was just asking why the community was down voting your question (and action that I highly disagree with here).